# Cannot implicitly convert type DbSet<> to IQueryable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

I'm created an oData in ASP.NET WEB API using from this documentation. [OData in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint). My EF is on another project so I just add the reference to my WEB API project. Upon creating my endpoints.

```
    public class ItemController : ODataController
{
    SAP_PORTALEntities db = new SAP_PORTALEntities();
    private bool ItemExists(string key)
    {
        return db.sap_item.Any(s => s.ItemCode == key);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Item> Get()
    {
        return db.sap_item;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<sap_item> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        var item = db.sap_item.Where(s => s.ItemCode == key);
        IQueryable<sap_item> itemModel;

        itemModel = item;

        return SingleResult.Create(itemModel);
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(sap_item item)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        db.sap_item.Add(item);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created(item);
    }
}
```

Got an error on this line: **IQueryable Get()**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<sap_dataaccess.sap_item>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<sap_portal.Models.Item>'. An explicit conversion exists
```

While the **Item** is my Model.

```
public class Item
{ 
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string Dscription { get; set; }
    public string ItemGroup { get; set; }
    public string InvItem { get; set; }
    public string PurItem { get; set; }
    public string SalItem { get; set; }
    public string UOMGroup { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string PurUOM { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> QtyPurUOM { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh yup! My bad for that, already edited my post. @MichaelRandall

Comment: Isn't this error telling you that you want to do `return db.sap_item.AsQueryable()`?

Comment: `return db.sap_item` => this line obviously throwing exception because the method return type is `IQueryable<Item>`. You need to do something like `return db.sap_item.AsQueryable()` to return `IQueryable<Item>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try to use linq `AsQueryable` otherwise you will only return `DbSet<sap_dataaccess.sap_item>` that will be converted type fail.

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Item> Get()
{
    return db.sap_item.AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: I just changed the return to DbSet<sap_dataaccess.sap_item>. The AsQueryable() return same error.